# Otimização de código php (geração de chave de NF)

Tags: php, funções, otimização

Caros colegas, atualmente estou trabalhando em um projeto que realiza o envio de cupons fiscais, nela eu cheguei a uma função que gera a chave da nfe, nela eu recebo os seguintes dados:

- Código da cidade
- Ano e Mês da emissão
- Cnpj da Empresa
- Modelo da nota (65 no caso)
- Série
- Numero da nota (9 posições)
- Tipo de emissão
- Numero da nota com 8 posições

Código da função:

```php
public function GeraChaveNFe($CodCidade , $AnoMesEmissao, $CnpjEmpresa , $Modelo , $Serie, $NumeroNF, $TipoEmissao){
    $NF8 = "";
    $NF9 = "";
    $Chave = "";
    $Digito = "";

    $tam = strlen($NumeroNF);
    if($tam > 0){
        $NF9 = str_pad($NumeroNF, 9 - $tam, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); 
        $NF8 = str_pad($NumeroNF, 8 - $tam, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }else{
        $NF9 = $this->right($NumeroNF, 9);
        $NF8 = $this->right($NumeroNF, 8);
    }

    $Chave = $CodCidade . $AnoMesEmissao . $CnpjEmpresa . $Modelo . $Serie . $NF9 . $TipoEmissao . $NF8;

    $Digito = $this->DigitoMod11($Chave);
    return $Chave . $Digito;
}
```

Minha dúvida está na seguinte função:

```php
function right($str, $length) {
    return substr($str, -$length);
}
```

a function Right faz o mesmo que o `String.Right` [VB e C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.right?view=netframework-4.7.2), ao pesquisar não achei a mesma função no php... então utilizei o substr.

A pergunta é, o substr é realmente o equivalente ao right ou existe uma função que possa substituir este método?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A pergunta é, o substr é realmente o equivalente ao right ou existe uma função que possa substituir este método?

Sim, a função `substr` do `php` tem a mesma funcionalidade da função `String.Right` do `Visual Basic`. Conforme [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.right?view=netframework-4.7.2) da `microsoft`:

> Retorna uma cadeia de caracteres que contém um número especificado de caracteres do lado direito de uma cadeia de caracteres.

Um exemplo usando a função `Right` usando [visual Basic](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic):

```
Dim TestString As String = "Hello World!"    
Dim subString As String = Right(TestString, 6)
'Saida :  "World!"
```

Exemplo retirado da [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.right?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Agora, o que a [documentação](http://php.net/) do `PHP` diz sobre a função [substr()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php):

> Retorna a parte de string especificada pelo parâmetro start e length.

Não irei entrar em detalhes sobre a função pois esse não é o foco da pergunta.

O mesmo exemplo de cima usando a linguaguem `PHP` com a função `substr()` :

```
$TestString = "Hello World!"    
$subString  = substr($TestString, 6)
//Saida :  "World!"
```

**Conclusão**

As duas funções são equivalentes e servem basicamente para a mesma coisa.

Obs: Recomendo ler a documentação da função [substr()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) pois a mesma pode receber mais parâmetros do que os usados aqui na resposta.

Comment: Obrigado Jorge, este fragmento de código é resultado de uma migração de tecnologia do vb para o php, então como o prazo é curto acabamos fazendo algumas "gambiarras" para o sistema funcionar, parabéns pela explicação

Comment: @AlvaroAlves que bom que lhe foi útil. Pode usar a função `substr` pois a mesma irá satisfazer o que você fazia no `VB`. Só recomendo dar uma lida na documentação para ter mais detalhes.